# How do I add a backslash after every character in a string?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I need to transform a literal filepath (C:/example.txt) to one that is compatible with the various WinAPI Registry functions (C://example.txt) and I have no idea on how to go about doing it.

I've broken it down to having to add a backslash after a certain character (/ in this case) but i'm completely stuck after that.

Guidance and Code Examples will be greatly appreciated.

I'm using C++ and VS2012.

Comment: `/` is not a backslash, it is a forward slash.

Comment: You're probably misunderstanding something; you should never have strings that actually have double backslashes.

Comment: I thought the registry was fine with forward slashes, but you can use `std::string::replace` to replace '/' with '\\'.

Comment: I do apologise, I do indeed mean / being replaced with \\.

Comment: @chris, won't that replace a *single* forward slash with a *single* backslash? I guess the question is about replacing it with *two* backslashes, and `string::replace` won't let you replace a substring for a substring, or a single character for a substring. Am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, please clearify.  Do you want the code to replace **one** forward slash with **one** backslash or **two** backslashes? It makes a BIG difference. I am leaning towards **one** because no API is going to expect you to pass in **two** backslashes in a file path.

Comment: I need to transform a single backslash into a double backslash.

Comment: @AndyProwl, `string::replace` will let you replace a substring with another, so doing `"/"` to `"\\\\"` will work. Anyway, yes, you need to loop it to replace all of them, or use something like, I believe Boost has one, a `replace_all` function.

Comment: Just to clarify what other people have saide or alluded to, you DO NOT need to replace `/` with `//` in string variables. `//` is ONLY used in string literals to add a single `/` in the variable. This means the entire premise to your question is invalid.

Comment: @chris: right, that's what I meant. And yes, you're correct about Boost's `replace_all`.

@Deanna: what you write would be correct of `\ ` (backslash), not `/` (forward slash). `/` is not used as an escape character in literals and, in particular, `//` does *not* turn into a single `/`. anyway yes, the fact that he wants to cope with single and double backslashes might sound suspicious, however the question is clear now: he has a string (*not* a literal) and wants to replace single occurrences of the backslash character with sequences of two backslash characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If replacing every occurrence of a forward slash with *two* backslashes is really what you want, then this should do the job:

```
size_t i = str.find('/');
while (i != string::npos)
{
    string part1 = str.substr(0, i);
    string part2 = str.substr(i + 1);
    str = part1 + R"(\\)" + part2; // Use "\\\\" instead of R"(\\)" if your compiler doesn't support C++11's raw string literals
    i = str.find('/', i + 1);
}
```

**EDIT:**

P.S. If I misunderstood the question and your intention is actually to replace every occurrence of a forward slash with just *one* backslash, then there is a simpler and more efficient solution (as @RemyLebeau points out in a comment):

```
size_t i = str.find('/');
while (i != string::npos)
{
    str[i] = '\\';
    i = str.find('/', i + 1);
}
```

Or, even better:

```
std::replace_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [] (char c) { return (c == '/'); }, '\\');
```

Comment: I'm having a few issues with the `str = part1 + R"(\\)" + part2;` line, The identifier "R" is undefined.

Comment: The R prefix indicates raw string literals in C+11. Is C++11 enabled in your compiler options?

Comment: ok, sorry, here it says VC11 does not support raw string literals: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx.

so you can replace `R("\\")` with `"\\\\"`

Comment: also, this CTP claims to add support for (among other things) C++11's raw string literals in VC11, so you might consider installing it: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515#overview

Comment: There is a much simplier way to code this without using `substr()` at all.  Once you have the index of a `'/'` character, simply use `str[i] = '\\';` instead. Also, since you already know that `i` specifies the index of the first `/` character, you should pass that value to `find()` at the end of the loop so it does not have to re-search data that has already been searched before: `i = str.find('/', i+1);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That wouldn't work, because it would replace *one* occurrence of a forward slash with *one* occurrence of a backslash. The questions asks how to replace one character with *two* characters (in this case, *two* backslashes)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You are right on the last point, I could pass `i+1` to `std::find()`. I overlooked that. I am going to edit my answer, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I do apologise, I made an error in my original question. I meant to ask how I would go about changing '\' to '\\'. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user1661022: no need to apologize, but what is important is to understand if you really want to replace *one* backslash character in your string with *two* backslash characters. if this is the case, then my original answer should address your problem.

Comment: Your original answer would work, however the line `i = str.find('/', i + 1);` Doesn't work because the backslash escapes the closing quotation mark.

Comment: @user1661022 :no, it doesn't, because / is not an escape character, only \ is.

Comment: @user1661022: well, if you mean `'\'` instead of `'/'` as it was in my original answer then yes, you have to use `'\\'` instead, because \ is an *escape character* in C++ and `'\'` won't compile. if you want to denote backslash as a character in a literal you need to write it twice.

Answer (score 1):

\\ is not two chars, is one char:

```
for(size_t i = 0, sz = sPath.size() ; i < sz ; i++)
    if(sPath[i]=='/')  sPath[i] = '\\';
```

But be aware that some APIs work with \ and some with /, so you need to check in which cases to use this replacement.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, strings are made up of individual characters, like `"foo"`.  Strings can be composed of printable characters, such as the letters of the alphabet, or non-printable characters, such as the enter key or other control characters.

You cannot type one of these non-printable characters in the normal way when populating a string.  For example, if you want a string that contains "foo" then a tab, and then "bar", you can't create this by typing:

`foo`<kbd>TAB</kbd>`bar`

because this will simply insert that many spaces -- it won't actually insert the <kbd>TAB</kbd> character.

You can specify these non-printable characters by "escaping" them out.  This is done by inserting a back slash character (`\`) followed by the character's code.  In the case of the string above <kbd>TAB</kbd> is represented by the escape sequence `\t`, so you would write: `"foo\tbar"`.

The character `\` is not itself a non-printable character, but C++ (and C) recognize it to be special -- it always denotes the beginning of an escape sequence.  To include the character "\" in a string, it has to itself be escaped, with `\\`.

So in C++ if you want a string that contains:

> c:\windows\foo\bar

You code this using escape sequences:

```
string s = "c:\\windows\\foo\\bar"
```

Comment: I know how to to it normally, as suggested. But I don't know how to do it when the original string is variable. (The string changes, so I don't know how to add the double slashes)

Comment: Double slashes are only used in **compile-time literals**, not in **run-time data**.  A `'\\'` literal at compile-time is a single `'\'` character at run-time.